# Django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

my django rest framework serializer returns errors in JSON Object:

```
{
"username": [
    "account with this username already exists."
],
```

how can i make it to return errors in json like this

```
{
"username": "account with this username already exists.",
}
```

my serializer code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from account.models import Account


class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Account
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'password2']
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {'write_only': True}
    }

def save(self):
    account = Account(
        username=self.validated_data['username'],
        email=self.validated_data['email'],
    )
    password = self.validated_data['password']
    password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

    if password != password2:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match'})
    account.set_password(password)
    account.save()
    return account
```

Comment: What if there are multiple errors? That’s why it’s returning an array…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in your save() method if such account exists and if so return a response:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
....
def save():
check_account = Account.objects.filter(username=self.validated_data['username']).first()
if check_account is not None:
    return Response({
```

"username": "account with this username already exists.",
})